# Crash on `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I have a paging `tableView` that loads a new page every time the user over scrolls, sort of like the instagram feed. The reloading of the `tableView` happens in a callback after the new page was fetched. The code looks something like this:

```
func fetchNewPage() {
    ws.fetchNewPage(completion: { () -> Void in {
        updateDataSource()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

At the same time, the cells in the `tableView` should be updated when the user taps on them (they change their background color). This happens after a call to the WS. The code looks something like this:

```
func markAsSeen(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     ws.markAsSeen(completion: { () -> Void in {
         self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
     })
}
```

My problem is that the `dataSource` can change the number of elements while the `markAsSeen` completion block is executing. Then the app crashes with this exception:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (50) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (25), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

So, my question is if you have any idea how to synchronize these two blocks so that the app does not crash anymore but also the row gets updated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What you are passing to the `func markAsSeen(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {` please add that code here.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with that. the method makes an WS call and on success it updated the object and should update one of the rows. The actual code it is a lot more complex, I cannot post it here

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about synchronization is correct. As an option you can perform updates of data source on main queue. In such case data source and UI updates will be queued and executed serially, as result change of data will be predictable and consistent.

Also it worth to mention that all UI calls is mandatory should be executed on main thread. From your code it is not really clear that it is true.